# Authorize attribute between requests

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, authorization

[This page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api) describes how you can use the `[Authorize]` attribute to restrict access to controllers and actions to authenticated or authorized users.

The authentication is done by setting the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, which then allows access to the restricted controllers/actions provided that the user is in any required roles.

When following this method, does the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` need to be set for each request (e.g. in a message handler), or does Web API have some way of maintaining that principal between requests? (As far as I know, Web API is stateless and there is no session, but I'm just checking.)

Furthermore, if the current principal is not maintained between sessions, what advantage does the `[Authorize]` attribute provide over writing your own custom access control scheme?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` needs to be set for each request in a message handler since the server is stateless.

Some benefits of the authorize attribute

- Allows to easily add authorization on specific methods or an entire controller
- You could specify multiple authorization attributes on a single action
- You can use the `[AllowAnonymousAttribute]` to disable authorization for an action
- Allows you to authorize on Role Claims or User Claims
- Provides valuable overrides to determine authorization